# Best Jenkins Plugin for Multiple Dependency Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

could you suggest best jenkins plugin to manage multiple level and complex dependency build?

similar to diamond

1. many build starts in parallel
2. downstream job will have to wait for two or more upstream job to finish before it triggers. e.g C job should wait for both A and B to complete and with build success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

---

Seems like [Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) is the one that will be officially supported and developed by CloudBees.

**Original Answer:**

---

IMHO The easiest to start with is: [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin)

**From the plugin Wiki:**

```
parallel (
    // job 1, 2 and 3 will be scheduled in parallel.
    { build("Job1") },
    { build("Job2") },
    { build("Job3") }
)

if (params["PARAM1"] == "BOO"){
    println "BUILDING OPTIONAL JOB4"

    // job4 will be triggered after jobs 1, 2 and 3 complete and if condition is met
    build("Job4")
}
```

Additional plugins to check would be:

- [Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin)
- [Tikal's Multijob](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)

Comment: @enthuguy You're welcome to accept \ upvote the answer if it was useful for you.

Comment: Thanks, i tried that. Its cool. But i would prefer to have build pipeline view based on that.  Or is it possible to have pipeline view bases on build flow plugin?.  Also on the build flow plugin can we do conditional check?  E. G. For loop or if condition?

Comment: 1. I afraid Build pipeline would not work, however there's a good alternative:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Graph+View+Plugin

Comment: 2. Yes it supports gread deal of condional or iteration logic. In fact everything that's supportted by 'Groovy' language which is a full fledged programing language.

Comment: Hi vano,  could please give some lead /link on the scripting?  Sample script :)

Comment: Edited the question to contain sample :)